# navigate and navigateByUrl not working correctly in ngOnInit on 2.0.0-rc.1

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Since the `2.0.0-rc.1` `router.navigate` or `router.navigateByUrl` doesn't seem to be working anymore correctly when used inside `ngOnInit`.

I don't get an error or anything, but it looks like the `navigate` happens too early, because right after it the `HomeComponent` is loaded and "replaces" the content of the `LetterComponent`. However the URL is correct (`/letter`).

If I put the navigate in a `setTimeout` with 1000ms it works again.

Do I need to use a different lifecycle event or am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug?

Note that: normally the value which specifies where to navigate to, comes from a cookie (is dynamic).

Here's my simplified app component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/letter',component: LetterComponent },
  { path: '/cv', component: CVComponent },
  { path: '/attachment', component: AttachmentComponent }
])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      // todo: currently not working correctly (issue?)
      //also doesn't work: this._router.navigateByUrl("/letter");
      this._router.navigate(["/letter"]);
  }
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Vtx.gif) of what happens.
When I access the app without a path it should directly navigate to the `/letter` "page" - as you can see the URL changes, but the content is the wrong one (the content is the one of the home component).

---

Update:

Here are my imports, if they are of any relevance:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
```

Here's my bootstraping:

```
import { bootstrap }  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Regarding @eburgers post:

Here's what I did:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, OnActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/letter',component: LetterComponent },
  { path: '/cv', component: CVComponent },
  { path: '/attachment', component: AttachmentComponent }
])
export class AppComponent implements OnActivate {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
  }

  routerOnActivate() {
      // todo: currently not working correctly (issue?)
      //also doesn't work: this._router.navigateByUrl("/letter");
      this._router.navigate(["/letter"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably you should do that trick
`setTimeout(() => this._router.navigate(["/letter"]), 0);`

Comment: As I already wrote, I know that it works with a timeout - even though with `0` it doesn't work because it's to early, but this clearly can't be the solution.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

So, I downloaded your code to see what the issue is.

1. the [Router documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor) suggests to use `navigate()` instead of
   `navigateByUrl()`. So you might want to change that.
2. It seems that the root route is overriding your subroute.

To resolve the issue, you simply need to put the current root route into a separate subroute, eg. `/home`.

```
{ path: '/home', component: HomeComponent }
```

I could not find any documentation for this behavior, but for a reason similar to this, even the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) at angular.io does not have a root route. It only has `/dashboard`, `/heroes` and `/detail/:id`.

---

*PREVIOUS ANSWER*

Looks like you are missing the ROUTER_PROVIDER in the @Component declaration.
Try adding that as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
```

Also, import the appropriate references:

```
import {Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help

Comment: I have updated the answer with the solution that is working with your code. Please see if this helps.

Comment: thanks it works, I guess this could be a bug, I'll report it to github.

Comment: edit: unfortunately it doesn't work, e.g. if you access `/home` directly, the same problem will occur. I'm pretty sure it's a real bug and I opened an issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8733 . Will post here when it's resolved. But thanks for the help.

Comment: That's pretty strange. I'm using your code and it is still working for me. Did you try deleting app/*.js and app/*.map, just to force a re-transpile?

Comment: I just cloned my own project freshly and tried it and it doesn't work... maybe we're talking about different things here?

Comment: Your link to the Router documentation doesn't work any longer; it appears to be https://angular.io/guide/router but the only mention on that page for `navigateByUrl` now says: "Always specify the complete absolute path when calling router's navigateByUrl method." Since there is scant little documentation for navigateByUrl, this answer is still pretty relevant, so you may want to remove the part about that method being discouraged.

Comment: @TobyJ, my answer was for the RC1 version of Angular2. Much has changed now. Let me know if you are looking for something related to this.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving it into `routerOnActivate` instead of `ngOnInit`.
You can do it by importing `OnActivate` and implementing it in your class.

Also make sure you are bootstraping your app with `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`.

Comment: I already tried this, interesting enough `routerOnActivate` is never called in my app....didn't understand why and thought it was probably normal so I changed it back to `ngOnInit`.... but maybe this is already the problem? PS: I am bootstraping my app with `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`.

Comment: Are you implementing it in your class? It will not be called if you are not. If you will provide your new code it would help.

Comment: Please share your html too.

Comment: why the html? Anyway you can find the whole project here (without `onActivate` though`: https://github.com/Nasicus/myAngularCV - does this help or are you looking for anything specific?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug.
I opened a new issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8733

When I get an answer / it's fixed I'll update this answer here with the solution (if there is any).

In the meantime there is a workaround, see @funkycoder post. Even though the workaround is for most users probably also not satifying.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already resolved this by now, but I wonder if the order of your routes is the real problem.  If I remember correctly, the router tries to match the path to the one given. So, in your listing, '/letter' matches the route '/' first, so it returns 'HomeComponent'.

I think if you had reordered your routes so that the route '/' was last, then it would have matched '/letter' correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's a bug or you are doing anything wrong. But instead of using the timeout method, I would suggest following approach:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.redirectToPath();
}

redirectToPath() {
    this._router.navigate(["/letter"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in other cases , probably  you have a href="#" in the  tag, wich is overriding after router.navigate