# Initially loading a angular 2 rc1 route that is not the default route

Tags: routes, angular

So I am updating my app to use angular 2 rc1 routing. I can initially load the default route '/' just fine. However I cannot load a non default route initially ex. '/app'. I get 'Cannot GET /app/'

app.ts

```
@Routes([
  {
    path: '/',
    component: HomeLayout
  },
  {
    path: '/app',
    component: MainLayout
  }
])

export class AppDomain implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _router: Router){ }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37300313/6238914). That should help you.

Comment: Why not just use 'useAsDefault: true' in the route that should be the default one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if you want to redirect to your HomeLayout component as a default route then add this to the *end* of your routes definition in your AppComponent (root component):

```
{ path: '*', component: HomeLayout },
```